# Whats app local backup on WA ver 2.21.18.17, migrated to new phone aug 21. 6th Nov reinstalled OS & WA 221.21.19 BUT Not able to use local backup

Tags: android, whatsapp

can anybody help to restore the manual back up from older version of backup

sequence of event

1. Stopped using Samsug phone with WA ver 2.21.18.17 and phone is intact but WA is not using SW is there as it is
2. Migrated to One plus migrated with local backup during first week of Aug 2022
3. This week (Nov 6) some problem call drop hence visited the store room and they suggested to format. Taken the back and given for reinstall
4. unfortunately Gdrive backup not working probably due to new version

Should i go back up to old phone activate and take the backup again which have few years data. kindly suggest. Tried with new phone if i try again it will lock for 24 hrs.

Any idea when this 24 hrs lock will disappear. Now my WA is working without backup.

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but **may** be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there). Please review [the guidelines for posting in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Comment: Whoever voted to migrate this to Super User: [read the fourth bullet under "not about"](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).